# how to view raw images on iMac or iphone

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app

I take a photograph with my iPhone were does the image go, both the RAW image and the jpeg. Seems like I have to use the Photo app to see these images but i don't know if they are jpegs or raw. They seem to transfer automatically to Photos. Is there a folder on my iMac or my iPhone where these images are stored?

Comment: Is this question about how photos are transferred, where they are stored, or how to shoot RAW on an iPhone? And which actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was under the impression that the iphone automatically generated RAW images yet I could never find any on either my iPhone or my iMac.

Comment: I have since learned that I need a 3rd party camera app to capture and save RAW images.

Comment: You need an app for that, the standard Camera only does JPG. Still, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: My question was simply where were the RAW images. Were they stored on my iphone or transferred to my iMac. This has since been explained to me.

Answer (score 2):

When you import photos into the Photos library on macOS, the images are stored in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/` (`~` = user directory)

To access the photos library, navigate to the Pictures folder using Finder and right-click (control + click) the photo library and select `Show Package Contents`. After that, open the `Masters` folder, and you will see your photos organized in folders by dates.

[image: How images are organized]

As far as I know, iPhones support shooting in RAW but not natively through the camera app. Please correct me if I'm wrong in the comments. Always delete photos from the Photos app to avoid corrupting your local photo library.

Source: [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2017/02/23/where-photos-files-located-mac/)

Comment: I found the location you mentioned. Thank you. I havea problem though in that Master only contains folders for 2018 and 2019, The 2018 folder contains images back to 2010. That doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: I am not sure, but it may be because that was the year that you imported the pictures and videos. If this is in fact the case, you could use the sort by "date created" in Finder.